# How to send data from client to raspberry pi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a simple remote control system using raspberry pi. I deployed web client application(that is node.js-based) on AWS and I want to control raspberry pi pin through client action.

For example, If I click a button on web page, LED that connected to raspberry pi pin turn on.

I'm thinking of running node.js server on raspberry pi also.
A signal generated from web client will be transmitted to node.js server on AWS, after that, node.js server on AWS communicate with node.js server on raspberry pi.

But, I have no idea what should I do.
I want to know the idea above is proper structure.
And What modules are needed for working it?
Do you have any idea or sample codes that can make it through? Please help me. Thx.

Comment: Take a look at a sample [AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdk-setup.html) project.  The AWS IoT stuff can be a bit involved but the instructions are good - be patient and follow the steps.  There are both C and node.js instructions.

Comment: I don't use AWS Iot proj. I just deployed my nodejs to EC2 instance. But thx.

Comment: Ok, then take a look at the [AWS IoT SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html) and publish an MQTT event from your EC2 to the Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple options (I'm sure there are more)

**IoT** (recommended, as @stdunbar said)

- use a lib like https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js
- have a script that always runs on the pi, listening to an IoT topic. Your website on Lambda could publish a message to this IoT topic, and your pi will catch it and run a script in response. I had this same setup on a project where you could turn on LEDs from an IoT button or website.

**Systems Manager**

- register your pi with AWS [Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager)
- once it's registered, you can run shell scripts on your pi using the RunCommand api.
- I have mine setup to run a 'git pull' on my pi code repo every time my AWS code pipeline runs a successful deployment. That way I don't have to ssh into my pi and update my code manually.

If you think either of these work for you, PM me and I'll help you through the details.